# ng-resource query returning all records

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, odata

i have ng-resource setup like this

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var storeCommandServiceRoot = '/api/StoreCommandsRest/:id';

angular.module('common.service')
.factory("storeCommandResource", ["$resource", "appSettings", storeCommandResource])
function storeCommandResource($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + storeCommandServiceRoot, { id: '@id' },
           { "update": { method: "PUT" } });
}}());
```

i am trying to get records by querying on a property called "Serial" which is an integer.

```
        function getStoreCommandsBySerial() {
        var storeCommandGet = storeCommandResource.get({ Serial: 3 });
        storeCommandGet.$promise.then(function (response) {
            debugger;
        });
    }
```

but in response i get all the records. and i am expecting only the records with Serial = 3. 
The url that is sent over looks like

http://localhost:xxxx/api/StoreCommandsRest?Serial=3

on the server side it is an oDataController with REST based functions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have inconsistent name with the parameter. In the factory, you have `{ id: '@id' }` but in your controller, you use: `storeCommandResource.get({ Serial: 3 });`

Try changing `storeCommandResource.get({ Serial: 3 });` to `storeCommandResource.get({id: 3 });`
Also, your storeCommandServiceRoot should be '/api/StoreCommandsRest/?id=:id'

If you intend to keep "Serial" in your url, make sure you change the rest to have "Serial" instead of mixing between id and Serial